# Finding Max/Min using Salesforce Flow

Tags: force.com, visual-workflow

I have a Custom Object which stores Territory_Name, Total_Capacity and Timezone.In a specific Timezone, I want to find out the territory which has maximum 
Capacity.

Using a fast lookup, I have the full list of territories in a Timezone. Now, how do I find the one with max capacity? Do I need to use looping or is there any straightforward way?

Which flow element can I use? and how?

Comment: Please give a try and if you face any issues then post with specific questions

Comment: Hi @SantanuBoral - I am stuck at first step itself. Using a fast lookup, I have the full list of territories in a Timezone. Now, how do I find the one with max capacity? Do I need to use looping or is there any straightforward way?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this more efficiently with a Get element that queries your Object filtered by Timezone, sorted descending by Capacity, and returning just the first record. When you sort descending, the record with the max value will be first.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You need a loop element to traverse through the collection/list of territories.
Then for each record, check the capacity and keep comparing against a temporary variable till you find the maximum. That's the answer